# My android app works on every device in the simulator but when I deploy the APK it crashes on marshmallow using camera?

Tags: android, android-studio, simulator

Basically, I have an app that I'm deploying through apk.

I have a user that needs to test it but is crashing on the camera. What happens is I have 2 imageViews that when you click opens a camera and after it changes the image to what you choose.

Now I already tested it on a 23 min api on my simulator and it works fine. When I was loading it to my user via sdk when she opens the app it crashes after picturing an image on the 2nd image view bubt it doesn't crash on the 1st one.

I'm completely lost as how to debug this. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/115145 If you do not understand the stack trace, edit your question here and provide a [mcve], including the stack trace and the code that was used to cause it.